# How to determine whether opendiff is installed?

Tags: mac-osx

As the title says, I want to determine whether the `opendiff` wrapper for FileMerge.app is present. I know of at least two places it can be located:

- `/usr/bin/opendiff`
- `/Developer/usr/bin/opendiff`

Is there a foolproof way to determine whether it's there - and, by extension, whether it can be launched by the user?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no foolproof way.  Oh using the various utilities,  you can make some educated guesses but nothing 100%.  Remember this also could be installed in /usr/local/bin/opendiff among other places.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't mind just checking in the most likely places, though. Are there other likely locations?

Answer (score -1):

```
locate opendiff
```

From the terminal will tell you where it's installed.

Comment: I thought about this, but this assumes their locate database exists, which - for users who shut down every night and never allow the `periodic` script to run - is not necessarily a good assumption. Correct me if I'm wrong here, though.

Comment: I don't know of any other sure fire way.  which opendiff  or the find command which could be slow.

Comment: This only works if the update process runs.  And generally a lot of people remove it.  Aside from that how do you know that is THE one that would be run.  There could be many different opendiff programs out there.

Comment: You're right. The which command when executed as the user will show which binary is in the path but you've already expressed your limitations with that. I voted the question up and hope to see a more creative answer.

Comment: Kinda silly that this was voted down when I answered based on the limited information provided.